# ES6: destructuring an object with symbols as keys

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have an object that contains symbols as keys. How do I do destructuring assignment in this case?

```
let symbol = Symbol()
let obj = {[symbol]: ''}
let { /* how do I create a variable here, that holds the value of [symbol] property? */ } = obj
```

I need to know if this possible, I do know the obvious and simple workarounds, but that's not what I am asking.

UPD. Funny enough I knew how to do that but typescript produced errors, and I thought I did something wrong in JS. [Here's a fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54004512/typescript-destructuring-an-object-with-symbols-as-keys) for typescript users.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use an alias (see [assigning to new variable names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names)):

```js
let symbol = Symbol()
let obj = { [symbol] : 'value'}
let { [symbol]: alias } = obj

console.log(alias)
```

Comment: The funny thing is I tried it and I knew it, but due to typescript produced errors for this, I thought I was doing something wrong.

Comment: Weird - it's supported by typescript ([docs](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/destructuring.html#object-destructuring))

Comment: Yes, but not this case with symbols.

Answer (score 2):

Use the same syntax for destructuring as for building the object:

```
let symbol = Symbol()
let obj = {[symbol]: 'foo'}
let { [symbol]: myValue } = obj;
console.log(myValue);
```