# Typescript: destructuring an object with symbols as keys

Tags: typescript, destructuring

Why this code produces an error `Type 'symbol' cannot be used to index type '{ [x: string]: string; }'.`:

```
let symbol = Symbol()
let obj = { [symbol] : 'value'}
let { [symbol]: alias } = obj
             // ^^^^^ the error is here

console.log(alias)
```

And most importantly, how do I fix this?

Comment: I dont think you can have an array as key.

Comment: @zahma I don't think too. But that's not an array, but a syntax for computed props and symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to declare the `symbol` as `const` to make the compiler infer a literal type for it and not the general `Symbol` type.

```
const symbol = Symbol()
let obj = { [symbol] : 'value'}
let { [symbol]: alias } = obj


console.log(alias)
```

This [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/15473) might be useful as to when typescript infers a unique symbol

Comment: Ha! So simple. And elegant, as always. There is a very important thing you said but I am not sure if I've understood it correctly. Are you saying, that `let` and `const` produce different types? Is this (Symbols) the only case?

Comment: Also are *a literal type* and *unique symbol* the same concepts in this context?

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev generally `let x = litreral` will infer the widened type while `const x = literal` will infer the literal type. So `let x = 'foo'` x is `string` while `const x = 'foo'` x is typed as `'foo'`

Comment: Makes sense! Funny enough, I almost always use `const`, but today for some reason wrote `let` and here we are.

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev you change `const` to `let`, ask an interesting  question, we all get point, it all works out :P

Comment: Answers usually get more upvotes in the long run, who knows. If you feel like chatting check your gitter :)

Comment: Eh, I don't know what you mean, I don't have an account there ) We'd just erase our comments, and that's it! If you meant to not pollute SO with them )

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev if you have a GitHub account you kinda have a https://gitter.im/ one too :)